# SQL query takes too much time (3 joins)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm facing an issue with an SQL Query. I'm developing a php website, and to avoid making too much queries, I prefer to make a big one looking like :

```
        select m.*, cj.*, cjb.*, me.pseudo as pseudo_acheteur
        from mercato m
        JOIN cartes_joueur cj
        ON m.ID_carte = cj.ID_carte_joueur
        JOIN cartes_joueur_base cjb
        ON cj.ID_carte_joueur_base = cjb.ID_carte_joueur_base
        JOIN membres me
        ON me.ID_membre = cj.ID_membre
        where not exists (select * from mercato_encheres me where me.ID_mercato = m.ID_mercato)
        and cj.ID_membre = 2
        and m.status <> 'cancelled'
        ORDER BY total_carac desc, cj.level desc, cjb.nom_carte asc
```

This should return all cards sold by the member without any bet on it. In the result, I need all the information to display them.

> Here is the approximate rows in each table :
>
> - mercato : 1200
> - cartes_joueur : 800 000
> - carte_joueur_base : 62
> - membres : 2000
> - mercato_enchere : 15 000

I tried to reduce them (in dev environment) by deleting old data; but the query still needs 10~15 seconds to execute (which is way too long on a website )

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does the explain plan tell you?

Comment: I guess the subquery is the problem. Try changing it to an outer join and checking one field for null aftterwards.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Further, for a question about query optimisation we will in due course need to see the EXPLAIN. But let's get the query right first

Comment: Read what @Strawberry wrote. Also read Section 4 of this answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 Then [edit] your question to show us your table definitions. That way we can try to help.  Or, tag your question [clairvoyance-required]  :-) -:)  Thanks.

Comment: Just define indexes to support every join.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look.

1. The use of `*` in `SELECT` clauses is **harmful to query performance**. Why? It's wasteful. It needlessly adds to the volume of data the server must process, and in the case of `JOIN`s, can force the processing of columns with duplicate values. If you possibly can do so, try to enumerate the columns you need.
2. You may not have useful indexes on your tables for accelerating this. We can't tell. Please notice that MySQL can't exploit multiple indexes in a single query, so to make a query fast you often need a well-chosen compound index.   I suggest you try defining the index `(ID_membre, ID_carte_jouer, ID_carte_joueur_base)` on your `cartes_joueur` table. Why? Your query matches for equality on the first of those columns, and then uses the second and third column in ON conditions.
3. I have often found that writing a query with the largest table (most rows) first helps me think clearly about optimizing. In your case your largest table is `cartes_jouer` and you are choosing just one `ID_membre` value from that table. Your clearest path to optimization is the knowledge that you only need to examine approximately 400 rows from that table, not 800 000.  An appropriate compound index will make that possible, and it's easiest to imagine that index's columns if the table comes first in your query.
4. You have a correlated subquery -- this one.

   ```
   where not exists (select * 
                       from mercato_encheres me
                      where me.ID_mercato = m.ID_mercato)
   ```

MySQL's query planner can be stupidly literal-minded when it sees this, running it thousands of times. In your case it's even worse: it's got `SELECT *` in it: see point 1 above.

It should be refactored to use the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` pattern. Here's how that goes.

```
  select whatever
    from mercato m
    JOIN ...
    JOIN ...
    LEFT JOIN mercato_encheres mench ON mench.ID_mercato = m.ID_mercato
   WHERE mench.ID_mercato IS NULL
     and ...
   ORDER BY ...
```

Explanation: The use of `LEFT JOIN` rather than ordinary inner `JOIN`  allows rows from the `mercato` table to be preserved in the output even when the ON condition does not match them to tables in the `mercato_encheres` table. The mismatching rows get NULL values for the second table. The `mench.ID_mercato IS NULL` condition in the `WHERE` clause then selects *only* the mismatching rows.